# Finding duplicates, which shares a common property

Tags: mysql, sql

I’m trying to select duplicated nodes on a Drupal site, basically i need to select nodes that share a common ‘tnid' (translation node id), and also share the same ‘language’.

But i can’t figure out how to write the query, i think i did the first part, finding nodes with common tnid, like so

```
SELECT origin.nid, origin.tnid, origin.title, origin.language
FROM node AS origin
JOIN (select nid, tnid from node
      group by tnid having count(tnid) > 1) common_tnid ON common_tnid.tnid = origin.tnid
#JOIN node common_lang ON common_lang.language = origin.language
                      AND common_lang.tnid = origin.tnid
WHERE origin.tnid != 0
```

Considering the language part is my big hurdle, how would i add that to the query? I tried a bunch of stuff, thus. the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  table1.nid nid,
  table1.tnid tnid,
  table1.language language,
  table1.title title
FROM
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM
      table1
    GROUP BY
      tnid, language
    HAVING
      COUNT(*) > 1
  ) dupe
  LEFT JOIN
  table1
    ON dupe.tnid = table1.tnid
       AND dupe.language = table1.language
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/294cc/1/0

Comment: Thank you so much @Frederick worked like a charm, i'll send you a virtual hug!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
SELECT origin.id AS origin_id, common.id AS common_id
FROM node AS origin
INNER JOIN node AS common ON common.language = origin.language AND common.tnid = origin.tnid AND origin.id != common.id
```

I dont know if your table has id field but you can change to some field that is different in both rows